# Is it's possible that PostgreSQL don't complete SQL updates at all because of locking?

Tags: postgresql

I have table with column `jobNumber`. Some values in it greater than 10.
I need to update it's values to make all of them smaller.

I wrote two SQL request and run them. After some times I checked console log. And there was errors about`locking`.
But as far as I know from docs if locks happens DB wait for unlock and continue execution.
I checked table data and there a lot of values `jobNumber` > 9. So update did not happen. Why? How it's possible?

```
UPDATE xml_files SET "jobNumber" = 1 WHERE "jobNumber" > 9 AND "jobNumber" < 12;
psql:D:/dump/job_numbers.sql:1: ERROR: interlock detected
ERROR: Process 7444 is waiting in ShareLock mode for "transaction 17499718"; locked by process 10304.
Process 10304 is waiting in ShareLock for lock "transaction 16365708"; locked by process 7444.
TIP: See server protocol for request details.
CONTEXT: When changing tuple (147470,18) with respect to "xml_files"

UPDATE xml_files SET "jobNumber" = 8 WHERE "jobNumber" >= 12;
psql:D:/dump/job_numbers.sql:3: ERROR: interlock detected
ERROR: Process 7444 is waiting in ShareLock mode for "transaction 17697349"; blocked by process 10304.
Process 10304 is waiting in ShareLock for lock "transaction 17535413"; locked by process 7444.
TIP: See server protocol for request details.
CONTEXT: When the tuple (40940,13) is changed with respect to "xml_files"
```

I did some DB settings turning, but I do not think that it can change behavior!

Comment: These don't look like the complete error messages. That would be a DETAIL, not an ERROR. Also, it would not say "server protocol" to the log.

Comment: There could not be any other process that insert new rows with "jobnumber = 9"? Also, did you check what are the processes 10304 and 7444  doing? They block each other, so it seems a deadlock to me. As Laurenz Albe said, this is not a complete message. Please provide more information.

Comment: But, they are not trying to modify same tuple(because of your predications), so it should not be a deadlock. Interesting! Could you provide information about the processes 10304 ahd 7444?